# Roxygen documentation: picture is not showing

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am trying to include a picture in the documentation of an R-package. I am using `roxygen2` for the documentation.

I think my code to include the picture is correct and the file is placed correctly in the `man\figures` folder. Nevertheless, the picture is not being shown in the documentation.

Roxygen code:

```
#' @section Figures:
#' \if{html}{\figure{eqFPKA.PNG}{options: width=100\%}}
```

The file exists and is placed in 'man/figures':

```
> file.exists(here("man", "figures", "eqFPKA.PNG"))
[1] TRUE
```

But when I run `document()` and inspect the documentation of the file it just looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the image is not displayed. It just shows an image icon.
I have tried inserting a path to a file that doesn't exist. That gives the exact same result.
I have also tried to run `install()`, restart R and run the documentation on the installed package. The result is the same.

Can anybody give me some ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: This is not `width="100\%"`, with quotes ? Otherwise here is the `viridisLite` example: `if(html{\out{<div style="text-align: center">}\figure{viridis-scales.png}{options: style="width:750px;max-width:90\%;"}\out{</div>}}`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you, but unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue. The icon is placed in the middle, but the picture still doesn't show. The code I used was just from reading the gt package documentation. That is the only package I can remember using pictures in the documentation. https://github.com/rstudio/gt/blob/master/R/summary_rows.R

Comment: According to [the docs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Figures) `The files containing the figures should be stored in the directory man/figures. Files with extensions .jpg, .jpeg, .pdf, .png and .svg from that directory will be copied to the help/figures directory at install time. `. You could check if the images **were** actually copied... Also there is no mention of `.PNG` (uppercase)... You never know ;)

Comment: Thank you @dario - .PNG in uppercase was the problem. The picture still doesn't show when   I run `?my_function`, but now the files are transferred during install and the help page is correctly displayed when I run `?my_function` on the installed package.